# Read text file and add to Listbox WP7

Tags: file, windows-phone-7, text, listbox, bind

I have a file in which the first line is a phone and the second is a date.
I read the file and add the content to a listbox fine and everything is in a different row.
Now i changed the listbox to contain 2 textboxes.

```
<ListBox Name="listBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
  <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel>
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Phone}" FontSize="32"/>
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyDate}" FontSize="16"/>
        </StackPanel>
  </DataTemplate>
```

How to bind the data from the file?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class to represent your data:

```
class PhoneDate
{
 public string Phone{get;set;}
 public DateTime MyDate{get;set;}
}
```

Then load your data into a list

```
List<PhoneDate> data = //load
```

Finally bind the list to the listbox:

```
listBox1.ItemsSource = data;
```

Now your bindings will work.

Comment: This is how i read the file
     using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
                        {
                            do
                            {

                                mPhone = reader.ReadLine();
                                MyDate = reader.ReadLine();
                                 
                                
                                this.listBox1.Items.Add(mPhone);
                                this.listBox1.Items.Add(MyDate);

                            } while (!reader.EndOfStream);

Comment: How to use the List<PhoneDate> data = //load

Comment: I manage to do that but the list is empty
'code' using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
                        {
                            do
                            {
                                mPhone = reader.ReadLine();
                                MyDate = reader.ReadLine();
                                list.Add(new PhoneDate(mPhone,MyDate));
                            } while (!reader.EndOfStream);
                            listBox1.ItemsSource = list;
                        }

Answer (score 0):

If you want them to lay out horizontally then you need Orientation="Horizontal" on the StackPanel.

If you want header and column alignment then ListView Gridview will do thatn